# Google Assistant SDK on RBPi 3: "...some basic settings that need your permission first"

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I followed all the steps described in [Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/run-sample) and installed the Assistant on my Raspi 3

- I have no problems with recording and playback
- Raspi running Python 3.4 in a virtual environment
- Assistant Python Library (no gRPC)
- Troubleshooting [Permission Issues](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/troubleshooting#hotword) did not help much (I have enabled all my activities)
- I have searched a lot for some similar issue but found all related with Google Home App and the enable of activities (I do not have any GH app as the get started example in "Assistant SDK" does not require it)

*When I run "google-assistant-demo" or the "hotword.py" script the assistant detects my voice saying "hey Google" but it answers "actually there are some basic settings that need your permission first" to any question.*

Is anybody having or had this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trying and trying I found the problem.

**Make a click on the option box *"Include Chrome browsing history ..."* when enabling your "Web & App Activity" ! (see pic below)**

If you do not click on it you will receive the message :

*"Actually, there are some basic settings that need your permission first. Just go into the Google Home app on your phone for more details"*

I hope this is useful for other people too because I did not imagine when I enabled my "Web & App Activity" control that this would be a problem...

[image]

Comment: More info here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/activity-controls I also need to check "Device Information" which was unchecked before.

Answer (score 0):

The following list of permissions is required to work with Google Assistant API: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/activity-controls

> Ensure the following toggle switches are enabled (blue):
>
> - Web & App Activity
>
>   - In addition, be sure to select the Include Chrome browsing history and activity from websites and apps that use Google services checkbox.
> - Device Information
> - Voice & Audio Activity